# AWS Lambda returns 200 to SQS when function times out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

**Resolved**

Human error. Even though status 200 was reported, the messages was not deleted when the function timed out. I had a side effect that deleted single messages from the batch.

---

I have a Lambda function that is invoked by a SQS Message. Sometimes the function takes a long time and then it times out.

Cloudwatch reports: `Task timed out after 30.54 seconds`

That is fine, but the SQS messages should then be retried because of this timeout/error, but in X-Ray I see that Lambda has error=true, but response status=200. That means the SQS messages are deleted.

I could do timing in the Lambda function and return an error if the code takes longer then the timeout, but is there a way to make Lambda to return an error (and not status 200) when it times out?

The functions are setup with the Serverless framework:

```yml
# the lambda function in serverless.yml
    receiver:
        handler: handler.receiver
        events:
          - sqs:
              batchSize: 10
              arn:
                Fn::GetAtt:
                  - ReceiverQueue
                  - Arn
        memorySize: 2048
        timeout: 30
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that your message is being deleted (it's not simply still in the visibility timeout)? Have you implemented the documented [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig) such as DLQ (with maxReceiveCount at least 5) and the source queue's visibility timeout to at least 6 times the timeout that you configure on your function?

Comment: @jarmod I have followed all of the above, but the issue was that the code deleted each message in the batch, but my internal message counter (in a database) did not update since the function timed out. So just another human error

Comment: Ah, I see. Were you able to solve the problem? Maybe by simply increasing the Lambda timeout and/or RAM size (which, tbh, is just reducing the probability that the problem happens, not solving it), or somehow ensuring that your message counter was updated correctly, or even removing the whole notion of a message counter so it couldn't be wrong.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I solved the problem by making sure I only update my counter if messages was successfully processed. I was tempted to just increase the timeout, but as you said - it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We were struggling with the same problem. How we solve it:

1. The lambda timeout is handled with middleware ([How to log timed out Lambda invocations](https://theburningmonk.com/2019/05/how-to-log-timed-out-lambda-invocations/), [middy](https://middy.js.org/))
2. We process the batch of messages from SQS and here pop-ups the following cases:

   a. all messages were processed successfully - return {statusCode: 200}, and the messages will be deleted from SQS

   b. some messages failed:

   - we delete the successful messages from SQS ([deleteMesages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteMessage-property))
   - throw the error in the lambda function, thus the failed messages will be not deleted from SQS and be retried automatically, depends on the config of SQS.